# change height of div based on elements within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically IF `div.PageheaderDescription` contains NO `img` and NO `div#cat-text` then i want the height to be 0px so there isnt a white space.

**Here is my css:**

```
.PageHeaderDescription {
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    width: 99%;
}
```

**This is the CSS path:**

```
html body div#Container div#Content div.PageHeaderDescription
```

**Below is the HTML**

```
<div class="PageHeaderDescription">
    <img border="0" src="images/Category/large/22.png" class="c1" />

    <div id="cat-text" class="c2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h1>1 Person</h1>
            </td>

            <td><span>test</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is using jquery the best way or could i use clear:both some how?
Could you help me, i am not sure how to check for elements in a div using jquery. I know contains works for string values?

Comment: you can try with CSS like `div.PageHeaderDescription {height: auto}`

Comment: I am going with auto, create an answwer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css `height: auto`

```
div.PageHeaderDescription {height: auto}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just set "max-height" to 320px. That way the div will default to 0 height, but will expand to max 320px height if necessary.

Comment: In some browsers (if not all) then just having whitespace in there will cause the div to default to the height of a line.

Comment: Good solution. jQuery is overkill here I think.

Comment: I opted to go for auto as IF the user inputs LOADS of text then 320px might not be big enough.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use the `:empty` selector in CSS:

```
.PageHeaderDescription:empty {display: none;}
```

Comment: I personally like this solution. However, it is worth noting that it does not work in IE8 or older.